# WCF Data Service reuse types in referenced assemblies

Tags: .net, entity-framework, wcf, odata, wcf-data-services

I have an Entity Framework 6 context exposed as WCF DataService (by means of `EntityFrameworkDataService<>`). The context is in MyApp.Data.dll, the types it uses are in the MyApp.Data.SharedTypes.dll. As the name suggests, I want these types to be shared, so that when I add ServiceReference of my DataService to some consumer the types would not be regenerated again in that place (of course, referencing MyApp.Data.SharedTypes first).

The common approach doesn't work here. There is an "Advanced" options window which allows you to tick "Reuse types in referenced assembly" when you are adding a service reference. But the button "Advanced" is inactive, it looks like these settings are not applicable to WCF Data Services, which is confirmed by [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/028ad495-a796-47a5-992b-c97eb5976981/advanced-button-under-add-service-reference-disabled?forum=adodotnetdataservices)

Is there any workaround I can use to share the types between my service and its consumers?